# Подсчёт нулей в конце строки

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, функции

Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы функция считала только нули в конце, а нули между обычными числами с двух сторон игнорировала. То есть результат ввода `'450700'` должен быть 2, а не 3.

```js
    let count = 0;
    function checkZero(result) {
        for (let j = result.length; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (result[j] === '0') count++;
        }
        console.log(count);
    }
    checkZero('450700');
```

Comment: ну или начинай с конца проверять на нули, и если встретил не ноль, то прерывай и выводи количество нулей

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkZero(result) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let j = result.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (result[j] === '0')
      count++;
    else
      break;
  }
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}
checkZero('450700');
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще и с помощью регулярных выражений, так:

```js
console.log('4500790900'.match(/[0]*$/)[0].length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, чуть быстрее :)

```js
function checkZero(result) {
  let j = result.length - 1;
  while (j >= 0 && result.charAt(j) === '0') j--;
  console.log(result.length-1 - j);
  return result.length-1 - j;
}
checkZero('450700');
```